# How to find the kernel panic log on debian

Tags: logs, grub2

I went to do a dist-upgrade on my virtual Machine with debian from 6 to 7.
When I boot on this grub configuration :

```
title           Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 3.2.0-4-686-pae
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=6cb76fa5-4efc-45b0-a8bc-e32dfecf7518 ro quiet
```

my system crashes with kernel panic like this snapshot :

[image: Kernel Panic screen]

The system is able to boot on this Grub config :

```
title           Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 2.6.26-2-686
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-686 root=UUID=6cb76fa5-4efc-45b0-a8bc-e32dfecf7518 ro quiet
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.26-2-686
```

I can not find any logs of the kernel panic in any log files in the var directory. I always find the log of the system when is booting well.

Comment: This seems far too early in the boot sequence and far before mounting local partitions so this message will not be written anywhere. (the error is in fact triggered by the attempt to mount the root filesystem, which fails...)

Comment: Eventually after a successful boot you can have it (kernel panic are stored in a special part of memory, for such cases). But for bug reports a screenshot it is enough (usually the early problem are easier to debug and needs less context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Patrick Mevzek that it's too early to be logged. I had the same issue and it was related to a wrong UUID upon boot process. Also once, upon migrating to proxmox, `/dev/vda` has beend renamed to `/dev/sda` and got the same message.

Comment: I understood and I found the root cause of the kernel panic as the initrd path is not present in the first menu. Thank for the promox tips.